# How to append new node to existing node in xml

Tags: vb.net

Following is my xml file code

> ```
> <XMLFile>
>  <EMail>
>  <From>
>   <Address>dddd@acd.com</Address>
>  </From>
>  <Receipent> <To>eeee@qwe.com</To> </Receipent>
>   <Subject>fffffsadasd</Subject> 
>   <Body>ggggasdsd</Body> 
>   </EMail>
>   </XMLFile>
> ```

i hve a sent button.On clicking that button each time i want to append Enail node and correponding childnodes to existing xml file.
In sent buttonclick i hve written following code.

```
Dim currNode As XmlNode
        Dim doc As New XmlDocument


        doc.LoadXml(("<XMLFile>" + " <EMail></EMail>" + "</XMLFile>"))
        Dim docFrag As XmlDocumentFragment = doc.CreateDocumentFragment()
        docFrag.InnerXml = "<From>" + " <Address>" + txtFrom.Text + " </Address>" + "</From>"
        currNode = doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild
        currNode.InsertAfter(docFrag, currNode.LastChild)

        docFrag.InnerXml = "<Receipent>" + " <To>" + txtTo.Text + " </To>" + "</Receipent>"
        currNode = doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild
        currNode.InsertAfter(docFrag, currNode.LastChild)

        docFrag.InnerXml = "<Subject>" + txtSubject.Text + "</Subject>"
        currNode = doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild
        currNode.InsertAfter(docFrag, currNode.LastChild)

        docFrag.InnerXml = "<Body>" + txtBody.Text + "</Body>"
        currNode = doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild
        currNode.InsertAfter(docFrag, currNode.LastChild)

        doc.Save("C:\xmlmailfile.xml")
```

What modification i have to make in button click

Comment: Do you mean multiple EMails in one XMLFile, or are you adding a new field?  Also, you might want to spell Recipient correctly if this file is for widespread use.

Comment: yes,multiple EMails in one XMLFile

Comment: For anyone interested in answering this question, it evolves from this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763177/concerned-with-writing-xml/

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it.  An XMLTextWriter might be better for your purposes though:

```
Private Function GenerateXML(ByVal emails As List(Of Email)) As String

    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder

    Using sw As New IO.StringWriter(sb), xt As New Xml.XmlTextWriter(sw)

        xt.WriteStartElement("xmlDoc")

        For i As Integer = 0 To emails.Count - 1

            xt.WriteStartElement("email")

            xt.WriteStartElement("From")
            xt.WriteElementString("address", emails(i).From)
            xt.WriteEndElement()

            xt.WriteStartElement("Receipent")
            xt.WriteElementString("to", emails(i).Recipient)
            xt.WriteEndElement()

            xt.WriteElementString("subject", emails(i).Subject)
            xt.WriteElementString("body", emails(i).Body)

            xt.WriteEndElement()

        Next

        xt.WriteEndElement()

    End Using

    Return sb.ToString

End Function
```

**EDIT:**

This need error handling etc, but should work for you.  There are some cases where it will break (such as if a file exists but is empty) which you will need to solve yourself.

```
Module consoleTestApp

    Private _path As String = "c:\output.xml"

    //Just pretend these are text boxes
    Public txtFrom As String
    Public txtRecipient As String
    Public txtSubject As String
    Public txtBody As String

    Sub Main()

        txtFrom = "from1"
        txtRecipient = "rec1"
        txtSubject = "subj1"
        txtBody = "body1"

        AddNewEmail()

        txtFrom = "from2"
        txtRecipient = "rec2"
        txtSubject = "subj2"
        txtBody = "body2"

        AddNewEmail()

    End Sub

    Private Sub AddNewEmail()

        If Not IO.File.Exists(_path) Then

            Using xt As New Xml.XmlTextWriter(_path, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

                xt.WriteStartElement("xmlDoc")
                xt.WriteEndElement()

            End Using

        End If

        Dim xD As New Xml.XmlDocument
        xD.Load(_path)

        Dim xN As Xml.XmlNode = xD.CreateNode(Xml.XmlNodeType.Element, String.Empty, "email", String.Empty)
        xN.InnerXml = GenerateXML()

        xD.SelectSingleNode("//xmlDoc").AppendChild(xN)
        xD.Save(_path)


    End Sub

    Private Function GenerateXML() As String

        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder

        Using sw As New IO.StringWriter(sb), xt As New Xml.XmlTextWriter(sw)

            xt.WriteStartElement("From")
            xt.WriteElementString("address", txtFrom)
            xt.WriteEndElement()

            xt.WriteStartElement("Receipent")
            xt.WriteElementString("to", txtRecipient)
            xt.WriteEndElement()

            xt.WriteElementString("subject", txtSubject)
            xt.WriteElementString("body", txtBody)

        End Using

        Return sb.ToString

    End Function

End Module
```