# Only one top level element is allowed in an XML document

Tags: xml, vb.net

Following is the code for inserting new nodes in an xml file .

```
Dim fleStream As New FileStream("C:\mailing.xml", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write,FileShare.ReadWrite)
Dim stmWriter As New StreamWriter(fleStream)
Dim writer As New XmlTextWriter(stmWriter)
Dim currNode As XmlNode
Dim doc As New XmlDocument

doc.LoadXml(("<XMLFile>" + " <EMail></EMail>" + "</XMLFile>"))
'doc.Load("C:\mailing.xml") '
Dim docFrag As XmlDocumentFragment = doc.CreateDocumentFragment()
docFrag.InnerXml = "<From><Address>" + txtFrom.Text + " </Address></From>"
currNode = doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild.AppendChild(docFrag)
currNode.InsertAfter(docFrag, currNode.LastChild)

docFrag.InnerXml = "<Receipient> <To>" + txtTo.Text + " </To></Receipient>"
currNode = doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild.FirstChild.AppendChild(docFrag)
currNode.InsertAfter(docFrag, currNode.LastChild)

docFrag.InnerXml = "<Subject>" + txtSubject.Text + "</Subject>"
currNode = doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild.AppendChild(docFrag)
currNode.InsertAfter(docFrag, currNode.LastChild)

docFrag.InnerXml = "<Body>" + txtBody.Text + "</Body>"
currNode = doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild.AppendChild(docFrag)
currNode.InsertAfter(docFrag, currNode.LastChild)

doc.Save(writer)
'doc.Save("C:\xmlmailfile.xml") '
writer.Flush()
stmWriter.Flush()
stmWriter.Close()
```

By executing this i cant able to view the result in IE,an error msg comes as 
"The XML page cannot be displayed

### Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet.

Only one top level element is allowed in an XML document. Error processing resource 'file:///C:/mailing.xml'. Line 2, Posi...

asdasd@qwe.com

When i open the xml file the datas are entered,Can anyone help me to solve the pblm.What modifications are to be done in my code?

Comment: why do you append the document fragment as the first child of the node, then proceed to insert it again after itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append new node to existing node in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767126/how-to-append-new-node-to-existing-node-in-xml)

Answer (score 5):

Well, this is quite normal. An XML document must have a root element that is not duplicated. You have already asked the related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767126/how-to-append-new-node-to-existing-node-in-xml) and originally [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763177/concerned-with-writing-xml/). Jon Skeet quite succinctly explained this to you already.

If there is an issue in understanding, you should consider reading up on XML or doing some research, instead of asking the same question repeatedly because most people will not realize that you have already received excellent answers to the problem.

If you keep doing the same thing you've already done, you should not expect different results.

Answer (score 0):

Open it in Notepad and see what the output is, and from there see what the error really is, and post it here if you need more help.